# problem with the background image and icons not aligning on the background Image

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This is what I am trying to make http://uupload.ir/files/lue6_web_1920_2.png and this is what I got so far(I only uploaded half of the picture because of being too big)
http://uupload.ir/files/ldto_capture.png
my 1st problem is that Inside my react component I do not know how to set these icons on the background image
2nd is that the page is not responsive with this code I have and I can't center have spacing between the cart and the user profile icon
lastly, everything seemed to be out of place.

```
import React from "react";
import './Home.css';
import Cover from '../Designs/adult-beautiful-beauty-413727.svg';
import User from '../Designs/user.svg';
import Cart from '../Designs/shopping-cart-black-shape.svg';
const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <img src={Cover} alt="cover" className="cover" />
            </div>
            <div className="nav">
                <img src={User} alt="cover" className="user" />
                <img src={Cart} alt="cover" className="cart" />
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Home;
```

CSS

```
.cover{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.nav{
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 100px;
    float: right;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Setting the icon on the background image you could use `position relative;` on the parent, and  `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;` on the nav. This makes your nav go to the top right corner.
- Making space between the nav items can easily be done by setting a `padding`
- When making responsive designs, look into [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

```css
.container{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.cover{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.nav{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
}

.user{
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.cart{
 padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x500" class="cover" />
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/ddff00" class="user" />
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/ddff00" clas="cart" />
  </div>
</div>
```